# Problem Spring returns empty response body for Spring Security and makes no change to validation exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, problem-spring

I've:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>problem-spring-web-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.27.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my `pom.xml`, I've this DTO:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

and in a `@RestController`:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @RequestMapping(value="/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SomeClass create(@Valid @RequestBody SomeClass someClass) {
        return someService.create(someClass);
    }
```

I'm using Spring Session with header session strategy. So if I remove `X-Auth-Token` header, I get an empty response body.

If I remove Problem Spring dependency, I get:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1640094286096,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/endpoint"
}
```

and for validations, regardless Spring Problem is in my `pom.xml`/classpath, I get Spring's default validation exception:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1640093786923,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotNull.someClass.name",
                "NotNull.name",
                "NotNull.java.lang.String",
                "NotNull"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "someClass.name",
                        "name"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "name",
                    "code": "name"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be null",
            "objectName": "someClass",
            "field": "name",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='someClass'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/endpoint"
}
```

How do I make Problem Spring kick in for both cases?

**Update:**

I've verified that `ProblemModule` and `ConstraintViolationProblemModule` are configured, but regardless `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` is called upon HTTP 400 exceptions. When `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` is excluded, the only change is that the response body becomes HTML rather than JSON. I have several `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` beans, tried excluding them to no extent.

Furthermore, creating a class such as:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SampleControllerAdvice implements MethodArgumentNotValidAdviceTrait {
}
```

resolves the issue for constraint violation cases.

Comment: The documentation suggests two things: first, as you are using Spring Boot, and as per your update, disable `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`: `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)`. In addition, you need to provide a `@ControllerAdvice` that implements and supports  `ProblemHanding`: `@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandling implements ProblemHandling {

}`. Did you configure both things in your application?